# Questions about the basic Api of kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin can use the createCoroutine() function to create a coroutine. In the description of this function, I cannot understand one sentence.

> To start executing the created coroutine, invoke `resume(Unit)` on the returned [Continuation] instance.

I don’t know if my understanding is correct. What I think is that before the resume() function is called, the coroutine body is not executed, but only exists in the Continuation object. After the resume() function is called, the suspend lambda expression is executed and Return the result.

Is this correct understanding?

Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: To be faire this is really not the "basic API" of coroutines. This is a very low level API that as a user of coroutines you should almost never use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is correct. Result of the lambda isn't returned to you, but passed to a next continuation (if specified).

`createCoroutine()` and `Continuation` is a pretty low-level stuff, usually you don't work with them directly. There are high-level alternatives for starting a coroutine from the outside of coroutine context. If you are not sure you really need to use `createCoroutine()`, then you are probably looking for: [runBlocking()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html), [CoroutineScope()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html) and then `launch()` or [GlobalScope.launch()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) (but read `GlobalScope` notes).